# Нужны ли вообще запятые в этих предложениях?

Tags: запятые

Раз я нанёс ущерб(,) как порядочный человек(,) я все возмещу.
Больше(,) чем что-либо(,) она любит деньги.

Answer (score 1):

1) Оборот ***как порядочный человек*** может обособляться или не обособляться. Обособление делается для подчеркивания значимости, а также иногда из структурных соображений для конкретного предложения.

Предложенный ранее вариант вполне корректен: *Раз я нанЁс ущерб, то как порядочный человек всё возмещУ.*

Однако он изменен: использовано местоимение ***то***, пропущено местоимение ***я***.

Если точно следовать тексту, то можно предложить такой вариант: ***Раз я нанЁс ущерб – как порЯдочный человек, я всё возмещУ.***

Здесь более сложная интонация, значимые обороты выделены.

2) ***Больше, чем что-либо, она любит деньги.***

В Нацкорпусе такие обороты активно обособляются, так как обычно есть **две сравниваемые величины** (деньги – что-либо).

**Оборот не обособляется,** если это условие не соблюдается или если есть еще какие-то причины, связанные со структурой предложения:

...но было в нем и иное, что сообщило облику Астуриаса характерность и больше **чем что-либо иное** **говорило** о его корнях. [С. А. Дангулов. Астуриас, Шикула (1981)]

И мне все кажется, когда я один, без конца, просто хожу по его улицам, что он сам, **больше чем что-либо** другое в мире, возник, вырос из этого опыта ...[А. Д. Шмеман. Дневники (1973-1983)]

Answer (score 0):

> Раз я нанёс ущерб, то как порядочный человек всё возмещу.

Придаточное с союзом "раз", аналогичным "поскольку", отделяется запятой. Во второй части не нужна запятая, не хватает частицы "то" и лучше не повторять "я".

Отказываюсь от своего мнения о том, что запятые во втором предложении не нужны, и думаю, что Sharon права: обособлять нужно, потому что сравниваются конкретные вещи между собой.